# Flash Builder: Define relative source link for linked lib

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

How do you define a relative link to the source of a linked library in Flash Builder (4).
I have a swc folder defined for a project. I want to link one of the contained swcs to it's associated source.

This works fine except that the path stored in the .actionScriptProperties file is absolute.
Here you can see the linked lib:

```
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="lib/myLib.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
```

And here you can see the linked source:

```
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="/full/path/to/project/folder/lib/myLib.swc" sourcepath="lib-src/myLib" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
```

The source linkage works fine using the full path setup. 
But if I change the path attribute to either:

- /lib/myLib
- lib/myLib
- /../lib/myLib

Then the source cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking swc using the "swc folder" method is the problem.

Relative source links to swcs are possible only if each swc is linked to the project individually. Then a relative path is used (in .actionScriptProperties) when you associate a source folder with a swc.